# Command to make another folder/file rwiteable (Shell Script Android)

Tags: android, shell, copy

I want to copy a script from the first `.sh` file to another file. But when the `.sh` file is executed, it say `Read-only file system`.

Inside the first .sh file this is the script

```
echo "echo "|=================--=================|"" > /system/0211/0211syscheck.sh  
echo "echo "|====================================|"" > /system/0211/0211syscheck.sh
```

I try this for copy script to a file inside `/system` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount `/system` `ReWritable`:

```
mount -o rw,remount,rw /system
```

and `ReadOnly`:

```
mount -o ro,remount,ro /system
```

you can also use it for other directories.

PS: these commands are for `linux terminal`.

Here is a sample code to execute this code on android:

```
//your command
String[] commandrw = {"mount -o rw,remount,rw /system"};

//cmds = your command;
public boolean RunAsRoot(String[] cmds){

    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process;
    try {
        for (String cmd : cmds) {
            process = runtime.exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", cmd});
            if (process.waitFor() != 0) {
                // Command failed
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

//put this code in a buttonclick or oncreate etc...
RunAsRoot(commandrw); //replace commandrw with your command
```

Comment: can you explain the script?

Comment: this is a command for in the linux terminal to mount a directory `ReWritable` or `ReadOnly`

Comment: I mean `rw` command at **rw,remount,`rw`** or **ro,remount,`rw`**

Comment: @AhmadFikriNurjihadDzulfikar Sorry, was typo and I fixed it. Please refresh the page.

Comment: i just need a simple script for Android but you give me more, thanks for helping me